# Are there any BigQuery limits on the Organization level?

Tags: google-bigquery

In the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas it specifies that the 2,000 slots limit are per project:

> Maximum concurrent slots per project for on-demand pricing — 2,000

We're experiencing this on the Organization level, i.e. the sum of slots used in multiple projects in the same Organization doesn't go above 2,000.

This doesn't isolate our dev and prod environments which is quite bad. Same goes for the number of concurrent queries.

Are there any undocumented limitations in BigQuery?

Comment: Are you using on-demand pricing?

Comment: @JinLee yes on-demand

Comment: Did you check the sum of slots in GCP console?

Comment: @JinLee yes I'm using Cloud Monitoring console to monitor slot usage

Comment: when you use Cloud Monitoring to monitor slot, doesn't it only show slots for the project you chose?   Is there a way to check slots at an organizational level?  So, I assume you expect to see 4000 slots if you have 2 projects?

Comment: You're right it only shows a single project. We eyeballed the slot usage for the 4 projects we have and inferred that there is some Organisation level quota the limits the slot usage.

Comment: The issue we experience that led to this question is we have spikes of queries in flight, but no corresponding slot usage increase. This causes very high query times. I'd assume if there is a spike in concurrent queries the slot usage should spike up to 2000, but we don't see it, slot usage stays constant, and approx. sums up to 2000 across all projects

Comment: Okay. If queries are heavy, BigQuery will use all 2000 slots.  And you will see 2000 slots used in all 4 projects.  Per project, it won't go above 2000 slots as you already know.  I think the best way is to ask BigQuery support team to find out whether there is an organizational quota for slots. :)

Comment: I see. Now I know know why you came up with the question!  I am curious as well!